# Filter one array using another

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a function that prints out a list of all courses with a passing grade but cant't figure out how. How may I implement that? (The minimum passing grade is 5.)

input:

```
courses = [Math, Geography, Chemistry]
grades = [7, 3, 5]
```

The `grades[0]` grade corresponds to the `courses[0]` course and so on.

Desired output:

```
Passed = Math, Chemistry
```

I have tried using `filter` but it didn't work, though I was using it wrong since the filter parameter is not an index.

It was something like

```
courses.filter((x) => grades[x] >= 5)
```

Comment: If you check the [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) documentation, you'll see that the index is the *second* argument.

Comment: since the question has been anwered; I'll add something else: Arrays seem like a questionable data-structure for storing key-value pairs (in your example the key would be the course and the value the grade) there are data-types specifically for storing such data (in JS that would be objects for example)

Answer (score 3):

The second parameter to the filter predicate (like most of the closures that can be applied to arrays) is the index of the element.

Use that to index the grades array...

```js
const courses = ['Math', 'Geography', 'Chemistry'];
const grades = [7, 3, 5];

const passedCourses = courses.filter((_, index) => grades[index] > 4)
console.log(passedCourses);
```

Answer (score 0):

`filter` comes with some [optional parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#parameters) you can take advantage of.

The "current index" of the iteration is the second one. Use that index to get the required element from `grades`.

```js
const courses = ['Math', 'Geography', 'Chemistry'];
const grades = [7, 3, 5];

const filtered = courses.filter((_course, index)=> grades[index] >= 5);

console.log(filtered);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing **index** please add index parameter in filter.

```
let courses=['Math', 'Geography', 'Chemistry']; 
let grades=[7,3,5]; 
let result=courses.filter((item,index)=> 
{ 
 if(grades[index] > 4){ 
   return item; 
 }
})
console.log(result)
```